# Passing member function of templated class to a templated function

Tags: c++, templates, macros, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I want to pass a member function of a class to a function in which I bind the function to an object that I have created. I succeeded to do this with a macro but I want to see how/if it could be done with an actual function(since I have heard macros are to be avoided when possible).
Here's my macro:

```
#define addCommand(string, function) commands_[string] = std::bind(&function, game_);
```

Here's how I tried to do it with a function but it doesn't work:

```
template<typename Game>
void addCommand(std::string command, void (Game::*function)())
{
    commands_[string] = std::bind(&Game::function, game_);
}
```

Comment: Why `&Game::function`? You already got `function` as a pointer to member. Just pass it along as is `std::bind(function, game_)`. And consider not using `bind` at all. Lambdas are superior in many respects.

Comment: what is the meaning of "it doesnt work" ? If you get error messages you should include them in the question

Comment: If you want generic functions, use `std::function`, and let the called use `std::bind` (or lambdas or anything else).

Comment: Yes that would be a possibility but i want to simplify the code since i would have to have the function in bind everywhere i call the function

Comment: Ok i figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: By making it simpler for yourself, you're making it less simple for the users of your code. And I also suggest you take a hint from the standard library itself: All functions taking a callable object as an arguments takes *any* callable object (through the use of templates). I also see more and more people recommending lambdas over `std::bind`, and with your scheme one can't do that.

Comment: Ok I'm open to doing that, could you elaborate on how to it the best way so It's simple for the users?